Deviations from IV-V-I progression
As an exercise in harmony I tried harmonizing simple children' tune (Au claire de la lune, see below), and run into the problem that the melody in bars 9-10 imposes the undesired V-IV sequence (dominante followed by subdominant). After looking up the chords, I saw that the problem is solved by using IIm(=ii) chord. I would like however to get a better theoretical understanding of what is happening here (and also why it is followed by the major chord: IIm-II-V-I) - I couldn't solve the problem by simply browsing through a harmony book, as it may be related to:

simply using II-nd degree chord (which however seems unavoidable here, rather than a matter of taste)
changing tonality (just for two bars? how can we see it?)
using double dominants or something else

The use of the major chord (here Dm-D) is also not clear - is it simply adding a flourish or are there more rigorous reasons for that?
I am only beginning to study harmony, but I would appreciate help in getting a bit ahead on this issue, as such deviations from the main triads seem to be rather common even in simple tunes.

(image source)

Why the heck is it written in 12/8, with dotted notes? Remove all the dots, put into 4/4, and it will make a lot more sense!

@Tim You are right - I took the image of the score from the page (linked in the Q.) where they make it "swing" - hence 12/8. But I have seen the same chord progression in many places (except one or two that actually use V-VI-I)

Just putting it into 12/8 doesn't make it 'swing' at all!

@Tim they do a couple more steps after that. I chose this specific stage, because it shows full harmonization without too many distracting features unrelated to harmony (apart from the dotted notes). Otherwise someone might have complained that it is incomprehensible, since the chords are not named in English.

What makes V-IV “undesired” for you? Do you not like the sound or does an exercise say to avoid it or what?


changing tonality just for two bars? ... using double dominants ... The use of the major chord (here Dm-D) is also not clear - is it simply adding a flourish or are there more rigorous reasons for that?

The technical term is secondary dominant. The Roman numeral symbol for that uses a slash, ex. V/V, which in English reads as "the five of the five chord." In the key of C major V/V is a D major triad.
When music changes key it is called modulation.
When music "changes key" briefly, as in this melody, that is called tonicization. Ex. "the V chord is temporarily tonicized."
The the other question you linked to, about I iii IV iv, that major to minor chord quality change is called borrowed harmony.
These concepts, while commonly used, are often found in the "advanced" part of a harmony textbook. That may be why you didn't find them with a quick textbook browse.
The other thing to consider is about the phrase structure of melodies.
Au Claire de la Lune follows a common |A|B| binary form with the measure counts for the phrases grouping as section A of (4+4) and section B of (4+4). It is common for such B sections to being with a "standing on the dominant" treatment of the harmony. Playing only a dominant or circular progression around the dominant like V, V V7, V I6/4 V, or V V/V V would be common harmonization schemes.
Another common option for starting the B section is to use a harmonic sequence, but that isn't the case for this melody.
The important thing is you can try to match common harmonization schemes to common phrase structures. Beginning phrases often work with simple diatonic V I, IV V I, ii6 V I, or I IV I type patterns. Middle phrases, continuations are often "standing on the dominant" or harmonic sequences, ending phrases use cadential formulas.
Of course those are broad generalizations, but they can be useful tools. Instead of groping about for harmonizing a melody pitch by pitch, you can first sketch out the general harmonization of the phrases, then fill in the chord by chord details and voice leading.

Thank you for filling some gaps (particularly in terminology.) Also thank for pointing out that I might be led astray by technicalities - I know this tendency of mine from other areas. Indeed, my current objective is to learn how to "fill in the chord by chord details and voice leading".

Re. voice leading. If you don't already know, there are three voice leading procedures for triads: move two voices, move one voice, more all three voices. It's simple but covers a lot. I have a cheat sheet of those three along with their common use in sequential harmony. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1USp2oh2GyK_FqNIt8B-RqVouAvjJC9-_/view?usp=drive_link

Probably the next important thing is about doubling pitches and tendency tones... but one thing at a time. Just post new questions as they come up.

At least when sounding things out mentally, I find myself thinking a string of secondary dominants, perhaps E7 to Am, then D7 to G could work.  Not quite the same pattern as the refrain in "Angles we have heard on high", but having the B section set out on a harmonic journey which ends with the dominant is not really any weirder than having it reach the tonic,.

I'd be inclined to use V for the 2nd half of bars 2 and 3, for example. Bars 8-11, I'd make all II (D major), which then acts as a secondary dominant which really does lead to the dominant (V, G)
And - dominant followed by sub dominant (V-IV) happens in quite a lot of music - 12 bar Blues being a prime example.
Use of ii instead of II (in reality V/V) will be mainly dependant on the one note which makes them differ being/not being in the melody. Here, there's no F in those bars, so either could be used.


I would like however to get a better theoretical understanding of what is happening here (and also why it is followed by the major chord: IIm-II-V-I)

You seem to understand already:


simply using II-nd degree chord (which however seems unavoidable here, rather than a matter of taste)


There's surely a way to avoid it, but probably using more advanced concepts.  You seem to be seeking to harmonize using only I-IV-V but not every melody is readily amenable to such treatment.  In this case, the use of ii (lowercase Roman numeral indicating the minor quality of the chord) is the simplest solution.


changing tonality (just for two bars? how can we see it?)


This is such a common feature of European classical music that it often goes unmentioned.  When it happens just for two bars or som it's not usually considered a full "change of tonality" but may instead be treated as a temporary tonicization of a certain scale degree, most commonly the fifth.  This means raising the fourth degree to serve as a leading tone to the fifth, leading to...


using double dominants or something else


In English these are typically called "secondary dominants," in this case, the D major chord functions as the "dominant of the dominant."
With older melodies particularly, where there are no chromatic alterations in the melody itself, the use of a secondary dominant is optional.  For example, you could play F♮ instead of F♯ in measure 11.  The sound is of course different, but it is a reasonable harmonization.
In addition to briefly tonicizing the dominant, it's also possible to move to other scale degrees, often the third or sixth (which results in a change of mode, from major to minor or vice versa), or, as one might do here, to the second.  The melodic move from D to A could be harmonized entirely as the secondary dominant, D major, as Dm to Am, or indeed with a few more options.
However, there is one more thing to mention: harmonic rhythm.  This refers most simply to the frequency of chord changes.  The basic harmonic rhythm of this arrangement is very slow -- with a couple of small exceptions, it's one chord for the first three bars of each four-bar phrase, and a different chord for the fourth bar.  You could well double the harmonic rhythm, as Tim suggests, by adding a G chord at the middle of m. 2 and m. 3, or make it even faster by additionally putting a G chord at the fourth beat of m. 1.  Normally you want to have a fairly consistent harmonic rhythm throughout (though some contrast in the third phrase would be typical), so if you do either of those things, you would want to make similar changes in the other phrases.
I just listened to part of Muzio Clementi's op. 48 (YouTube score video, performance by Maria Tipo, cued to skip the opening fantasia), which is a set of variations on this tune, and, speaking of harmonic rhythm, he speeds things up in the third measure, having one chord per beat, with the last two having a classic baroque-style cadence of ii(6/5)-V-I, where ii(6/5) denotes (in C major) a Dm7 chord in first inversion (i.e., with F in the bass, so, in lead sheet terms, Dm7/F).  For m. 9, he has G major, and in m. 10, D major, so V-V/V (where V/V, "five of five," denotes the secondary dominant).

Thank you. To understand things better: in 9-10 the melody contains only re and la - since one avoids using G-F chords, Dm seems like the simplest option, as it consonant with the melody. Are there are stricter rules on which chords one can or cannot use to avoid V-VI ?

@RogerV. It depends on the melody and on the musical style.  The harmonization given in the question is a particularly simple one that you might see in a book of music for children.  The chords that are available depend on how far you are prepared to deviate from the key into related (or less closely related) tonic areas.  The more you deviate, the more the music will sound like Wagner or Stravinsky and less like folk music or children's music.  And avoiding V-IV is also just a matter of style -- you will find songs that do this in certain styles.
